# C# - trying to create a console board game but can't get game to iterate through loop indefinitely

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

So i've pretty much got up to 6 objects which are players, and they move depending on a dice roll. The game works although i'm struggling to get the game to iterate through each players turn while the game isn't over.

so far i'm pretty much saying:

```
foreach (player in players)
{
     while (player.finish == false)
     {
          play_turn();
     }
}
```

But with a while loop it will stay on player 1's turn until they finish the game, then go to player 2. Whereas if I use an if instead of a while it will only iterate for as many players are in the game...

Maybe i've been overthinking it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need the while around the foreach, not the other way around; determining if the game is finished needs to be done differently (e.g. just have a count of players still remaining in the game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must wrap the `while` around the `foreach`. The `while` would check if the game is over on each iteration. Within the `foreach`, each player will take turns until the game is over.

Consider the example below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class Player
    {
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static Player _currentTurn;
        public static bool _isGameOver;
        public static System.Timers.Timer _gameTimer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _gameTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            _gameTimer.Elapsed += _gameTimer_Elapsed;

            var players = new List<Player>()
            {
                new Player() { PlayerName = "Player1" },
                new Player() { PlayerName = "Player2" },
                new Player() { PlayerName = "Player3" }
            };

            _gameTimer.Start();

            while (!_isGameOver)
            {
                foreach (var player in players)
                {
                    _currentTurn = player;

                    PlayTurn();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");
        }

        private static void _gameTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _isGameOver = true;
            _gameTimer.Stop();
        }

        public static void PlayTurn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_currentTurn.PlayerName} took their turn.");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

A timer is created; once elapsed, the game ends. Within the confines of the timer's life, the players each take turns.